# Django, отправка почты smtp через SSL

Tags: django

Не удается отправить письмо - выдает такую ошибку:

> SSLError [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number
> (_ssl.c:1056)

Настройки почты в settings.py такие:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "mail.*.ru"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "info@*.ru"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "***"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "job@*.ru"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

Comment: Порт 587 намекает, что вместо настройки `EMAIL_USE_SSL` нужно использовать настройку `EMAIL_USE_TLS`

Comment: Так выдает SMTPAuthenticationError (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful'). Я точно не знаю какой порт, может 465, но на сервере должен быть SSL

Comment: Ну а 'Authentication unsuccessful' в свою очередь намекает, что неверное имя пользователя или неверный пароль